# How do I create a submit button for a wordpress hosted blog?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to create a button for a wordpress blog that does just what the digg button does for Digg. Anybody can paste a code to their website or blog which will generate a button. When the button is pressed, I want the link that they are on and maybe a little content to be submitted to my blog. I searched ... but no luck. If anybody can help me out, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the HTML:

> [digg=http://digg.com/(path to your
>   submission)]

e.g.

> [digg=http://digg.com/microsoft/Another_Vista_Oddity_The_Invisible_Control_box_and_menu]

That will give you a Digg button as in the [example](http://whyamistilltyping.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/another-vista-oddity/).

Comment: Cool .. thanks for the answer. So if I would want to replace "digg" with my own site ... what should I do?

Comment: You probably can't - the digg script is provided by wordpress. Unless you are self hosted you won't be able to add active scripting to your blog.

Comment: I am self hosted. I can edit everything on the template. I know that it should be javascript. And wordpress does have a Press This button. I was thinking of using that somehow. But I'm sure that there are better ways of doing this.